# How to overlay WMS layer on 3D Tiles in Cesium?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

When I try to overlay a WMS layer on top of a 3D Tiles model, I find that the 3D Tiles model always covers any layers. I have checked the official documentation of Cesium and there doesn't seem to be a direct API available for this. How can I overlay this WMS layer on top of the 3D Tiles model? Thank you everyone in advance.

I have tried setting the WMS layer as a material and also setting it as a PNG, but the issue remains.